# I've trying to make a simple application in visual basic.NET,

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to Visual Basic.NET and I've been trying to make this simple application. It's a tax calculator.

Two-dimensional arrays are a bit... well not easy for me to grasp yet. So my question is: can you take a look at my code and give me hints on how to solve this issue?

When I run the code in the Labelbox I get a result of 0.00

```
Public Class PerrytownForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call

    End Sub

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If Not (components Is Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents IdFwtLabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents FwtLabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents CalculateButton As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents ExitButton As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents StatusGroupBox As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    Friend WithEvents MarriedRadioButton As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents SingleRadioButton As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents IdTaxableLabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents TaxableTextBox As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.Container

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.IdTaxableLabel = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.StatusGroupBox = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
        Me.MarriedRadioButton = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.SingleRadioButton = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.TaxableTextBox = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.IdFwtLabel = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.FwtLabel = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.CalculateButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.ExitButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.StatusGroupBox.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'IdTaxableLabel
        '
        Me.IdTaxableLabel.AutoSize = True
        Me.IdTaxableLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(24, 24)
        Me.IdTaxableLabel.Name = "IdTaxableLabel"
        Me.IdTaxableLabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(99, 16)
        Me.IdTaxableLabel.TabIndex = 0
        Me.IdTaxableLabel.Text = "&Taxable wages:"
        '
        'StatusGroupBox
        '
        Me.StatusGroupBox.Controls.Add(Me.MarriedRadioButton)
        Me.StatusGroupBox.Controls.Add(Me.SingleRadioButton)
        Me.StatusGroupBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(184, 24)
        Me.StatusGroupBox.Name = "StatusGroupBox"
        Me.StatusGroupBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(95, 88)
        Me.StatusGroupBox.TabIndex = 2
        Me.StatusGroupBox.TabStop = False
        Me.StatusGroupBox.Text = "Status"
        '
        'MarriedRadioButton
        '
        Me.MarriedRadioButton.Checked = True
        Me.MarriedRadioButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(8, 21)
        Me.MarriedRadioButton.Name = "MarriedRadioButton"
        Me.MarriedRadioButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(80, 24)
        Me.MarriedRadioButton.TabIndex = 0
        Me.MarriedRadioButton.TabStop = True
        Me.MarriedRadioButton.Text = "&Married"
        '
        'SingleRadioButton
        '
        Me.SingleRadioButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(8, 50)
        Me.SingleRadioButton.Name = "SingleRadioButton"
        Me.SingleRadioButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(80, 24)
        Me.SingleRadioButton.TabIndex = 1
        Me.SingleRadioButton.Text = "&Single"
        '
        'TaxableTextBox
        '
        Me.TaxableTextBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(24, 40)
        Me.TaxableTextBox.Name = "TaxableTextBox"
        Me.TaxableTextBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(136, 23)
        Me.TaxableTextBox.TabIndex = 1
        '
        'IdFwtLabel
        '
        Me.IdFwtLabel.AutoSize = True
        Me.IdFwtLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(24, 80)
        Me.IdFwtLabel.Name = "IdFwtLabel"
        Me.IdFwtLabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 16)
        Me.IdFwtLabel.TabIndex = 5
        Me.IdFwtLabel.Text = "Federal withholding tax:"
        '
        'FwtLabel
        '
        Me.FwtLabel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.FwtLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(24, 96)
        Me.FwtLabel.Name = "FwtLabel"
        Me.FwtLabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(136, 23)
        Me.FwtLabel.TabIndex = 6
        Me.FwtLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        '
        'CalculateButton
        '
        Me.CalculateButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(184, 120)
        Me.CalculateButton.Name = "CalculateButton"
        Me.CalculateButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 25)
        Me.CalculateButton.TabIndex = 3
        Me.CalculateButton.Text = "&Calculate Tax"
        '
        'ExitButton
        '
        Me.ExitButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(184, 152)
        Me.ExitButton.Name = "ExitButton"
        Me.ExitButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 25)
        Me.ExitButton.TabIndex = 4
        Me.ExitButton.Text = "E&xit"
        '
        'PerrytownForm
        '
        Me.AcceptButton = Me.CalculateButton
        Me.AutoScaleBaseSize = New System.Drawing.Size(6, 16)
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(312, 205)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.StatusGroupBox)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.ExitButton)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.CalculateButton)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.FwtLabel)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.IdFwtLabel)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TaxableTextBox)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.IdTaxableLabel)
        Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Name = "PerrytownForm"
        Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        Me.Text = "Perrytown Gift Shop"
        Me.StatusGroupBox.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub

#End Region

    'declare form-level arrays
    Private msngSingle(,) As Single = {{51, 0, 0, 0},
                                       {552, 0, 0.15, 51},
                                       {1196, 75.15, 0.28, 552},
                                       {2662, 255.47, 0.31, 1196},
                                       {5750, 709.93, 0.36, 2662},
                                       {99999, 1821.61, 0.396, 5750}}

    Private msngMarried(,) As Single = {{124, 0, 0, 0},
                                        {960, 0, 0.15, 124},
                                        {2023, 124.4, 0.28, 960},
                                        {3292, 423.04, 0.31, 2023},
                                        {5809, 816.43, 0.36, 3292},
                                        {99999, 1722.55, 0.396, 5809}}

    Private Sub ExitButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TaxableTextBox_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TaxableTextBox.Enter
        Me.TaxableTextBox.SelectAll()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearLabels(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MarriedRadioButton.Click, SingleRadioButton.Click, TaxableTextBox.TextChanged
        Me.FwtLabel.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
        Dim sngTaxTable(5, 3) As Single
        Dim sngTaxable, sngFwt As Single, intRow As Integer
        Dim blnFound As Boolean

        'assign taxable wages to a variable
        sngTaxable = Val(Me.TaxableTextBox.Text)

        'determine appropriate array
        If Me.SingleRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            sngTaxable = msngSingle
        Else
            sngTaxable = msngMarried
        End If

        'search for taxable wages in the first column in the array
        Do While intRow < 6 AndAlso blnFound = False
            If sngTaxable <= sngTaxTable(intRow, 0) Then
                'calculate the fwt
                sngFwt = sngTaxTable(intRow, 1) _
                    + sngTaxTable(intRow, 2) _
                    * (sngTaxable - sngTaxTable(intRow, 3))
                blnFound = True
            Else
                intRow = intRow + 1

            End If
        Loop
        'display the fwt
        Me.FwtLabel.Text = Format(sngFwt, "currency")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @Nibuja has brought attention to something important. To make sure that you do not accidentally make a new variable through a misspelling, always declare ‘Option Explicit’ at the top of your modules. This forces you to declare (dim) each variable that you use and will raise an error otherwise.

Comment: Please take care to use the correct TAGS when marking your question. VB.NET and VBA are *NOT* the same thing. The description of the VBA tag even mentions this explicitly! If you don't use the right tags, you won't reach the right people. And you'll annoy people who are looking for VBA-specific things.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code for myself and found some mistake: You forgot the letter "T"

```
If Me.SingleRadioButton.Checked = True Then
    sngTaxable = msngSingle
Else
    sngTaxable = msngMarried
End If
```

needs to be

```
If Me.SingleRadioButton.Checked = True Then
    sngTaxTable = msngSingle
Else
    sngTaxTable = msngMarried
End If
```

If I change this, the code will work and give some results, if I try to enter some numbers. 
If they are too little or big, the program doesn't do anything. I don't know if this is intentional, but maybe a little error output (MsgBox etc) could be nice.

Comment: Thank you all for all your responses.

Comment: @Joey Grant i'll definitely will be trying and applying/declaring option Explicit.

Comment: @Cindy meister thanks for your input. its a well logical notice, honestly i didn't know that vba and vb.net are two different things. i shall not make this mistake moving forward.

Comment: @ Nibuja I've tried your solution and it works. thanks again for your key eye. i'll try to include an exception a try/throw statement. well again thanks  for your help

Comment: No problem, I'm glad i could help